# PowerBi measure and summarize row for report

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBi.

What I am trying to do is summarize an email marketing report for open, clicks with the exported data. The data looks like

```
|   Campaign Name  |     Email Address     | Event Type |
|:---------------: |:---------------------:| :--------: |
| Test Campaign    | test@example.com      | Open       |
| Test Campaign    | test@example.com      | Open       |
| Test Campaign    | test123@example.com   | Open       |
| Test Campaign 2  | test@example.com      | Open       |
| Test Campaign 2  | test@example.com      | Open       |
| Test Campaign 2  | test1234@example.com  | Open       |
| Test Campaign 2  | test@example.com      | Clicked    |
| Test Campaign 2  | test@example.com      | Clicked    |
```

I want to calculate each event type that is unique for each email address and summarize it by the campaign name. There can be duplicate email address if someone opens email twice. And there are multiple different campaign names

I want PowerBI to be able to take the above data and summarize it as such with a measure formula :

| Campaign Name | Open | Click |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test Campaign | 2 | 0 |
| Test Campaign 2 | 2 | 1 |

Any suggestions? I can't get it to summarize by campaign name.

```
Clicks = Calculate(DistinctCount('table'[column]),'table2 for event type'[event type] = "click"))
```

Comment: You do not give us enough data . It seems like you work with 2 tables so I suspect there is a relation between them? Please enhance and document your question a bit better so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, table errors after the 2nd row, so I turned it into a "code" so that I can submit. Hopefully it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in DAX very quickly.

**In PowerBI, you create two new measures:**

Please note that I've used `'Table'` as the table name, replace it with the actual name of your table.

```
'Table'[Open_Nb] =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Email Address ]),
    'Table'[Event Type] = "Open"
)
```

and

```
'Table'[Clicked_Nb] =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Email Address ]),
    'Table'[Event Type] = "Clicked"
)
```

Then you can use this table two ways. You can create a new *Table* visual and drag and drop :

- `Campaign Name`
- Measure `Open_Nb`
- Measure `Clicked_Nb`

Or, directly as a new table with the expression :

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Campaign Name ]
    ),
    "Open",
    'Table'[Open_Nb],
    "Click",
    'Table'[Clicked_Nb]
)
```